# Create Bitmap on MENUITEMINFO Wont load bitmap

Tags: c++, bitmap, menu

The program fails to even load the dropdown now once the hbmpItem is added. Any ideas how I can add a small bitmap to my menu? Have removed items from the code to clean it up for this question.

Stepping through the program shows that there is nothing in memory for the bitmap variables which to me means it failed to load. The paths are correct.

UPDATE: Answer see below.

```
               MENUITEMINFO mii;

                memset(&mii, 0, sizeof(mii));
                mii.cbSize = sizeof(mii);
                mii.fMask = MIIM_BITMAP; //| MIIM_BITMAP;
                mii.fType = MFT_BITMAP;
                mii.dwTypeData = const_cast<char*>(pMenuRec->GetName());
                mii.cch = strlen(pMenuRec->GetName());
                mii.wID = pMenuRec->GetID();
                mii.hbmpItem = image;      // hBMP;  // need to add bitmap handle
                mii.dwItemData = reinterpret_cast<unsigned long>(pMenuRec->GetName());
                InsertMenuItem(hMenu, pMenuRec->GetID(), FALSE, &mii);


                memset(&mii,0,sizeof(mii));
                mii.cbSize     = sizeof(mii);
                mii.fMask = MIIM_TYPE | MIIM_DATA | MIIM_ID; //| MIIM_BITMAP;
                mii.fType = MFT_STRING;
                mii.dwTypeData = const_cast<char*>(pMenuRec->GetName());
                mii.cch        = strlen(pMenuRec->GetName());
                mii.wID        = pMenuRec->GetID();
                //mii.hbmpItem =  image;      // hBMP;  // need to add bitmap handle
                mii.dwItemData = reinterpret_cast<unsigned long>(pMenuRec->GetName());

                InsertMenuItem(hMenu,pMenuRec->GetID(),FALSE,&mii);
```

Comment: Should `mii.fType = MFT_STRING;` actually be `mii.fType = MFT_BITMAP;`?

Comment: I feel like there should be the code above, followed by another menuiteminfo for the image to be displayed with that value in it instead? Like one for string one for bitmap but I cant find any examples of drawing the bitmap using hbmpitem

Comment: OK so I have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: `Anyone know how to combine them onto one?` check out `hbmpChecked` and `hbmpUnchecked`

Comment: @paulsanders Cheers I just actually started looking for it so you nailed it. Now need to find the correct fmask and ftype commands to use for it..

Comment: @paulsanders thanks for the time, got it!

Answer (score 0):

Easy mistake to make `"C:\mybitmap.bmp"` should be `"C:\\mybitmap.bmp"`. Remember backslash is an escape character in string literals., if you want a backslash in a string literal then you must double it.

Also worth noting that most functions work perfectly well with forward slashes on Windows. So you could change the backslash to a forward slash.

Incidentally in your code why are you loading the bitmap twice?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. Twice as im just trying difference methods to get it to work and wasn't sure if I was doing it right. The path name doesn't appear to work even with the extra "\" for example my actual bitmap path is D:\\Folder1\\Folder2\\Folder3\\Folder4\\test.bmp I changed this and no luck either. If I load it in file explorer with the single "\" it loads the image in windows picture viewer so I know the path works.. If you have any ideas its appreciated, been on this for a day now

Comment: Well, the first thing to do after any Windows API failure is to call `GetLastError()` which will return an error code which you can lookup to hopefully get some idea of the error.

Comment: Hi John, I have updated the question. I also did try get last error and after tinkering the image is displayed, but now menu item info needs to have a bitmap and text on the same line. Currently only can get it working with the flags with a new one on each line

Answer (score 0):

So image and text is not allowed. SO checked and unchecked was used by adding the fmask

```
                memset(&mii,0,sizeof(mii));
                mii.cbSize     = sizeof(mii);
                mii.fMask = MIIM_TYPE | MIIM_SUBMENU | MIIM_DATA | MIIM_ID | MIIM_CHECKMARKS; // Add checkmarks;
                mii.fType = MFT_STRING;
                mii.dwTypeData = const_cast<char*>(pMenuRec->GetName());
                mii.cch        = strlen(pMenuRec->GetName());
                mii.wID        = pMenuRec->GetID();
                mii.hbmpChecked = image;
                mii.hbmpUnchecked = image;
                mii.dwItemData = reinterpret_cast<unsigned long>(pMenuRec->GetName());
                InsertMenuItem(hMenu, pMenuRec->GetID(), FALSE, &mii);`
```